# Runtime exception while executing sqoop job

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, sqoop, sqoop2, biginsights

I am trying to execute sqoop job in biginsights. I am importing data from oracle db to hdfs. Below is the sqoop command which starts executing mapper and stops after sometime.

```
sudo sqoop import --connect "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ***.**.**.***)(PORT = 1908)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = GPRSDB1) ) )" --username **** --password ***** --query "select distinct pr_con_id from s_org_ext where \$CONDITIONS" --where "PAR_DIVN_ID ='1-1POG9V' AND rownum< 100" --target-dir /user/bigsql/crm/s_contact_mh --fields-terminated-by ',' --m 1
```

Below is the error :

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:167)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:746)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:220)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:165)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:199)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:480)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:413)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:508)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:203)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:33)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:510)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBConfiguration.getConnection(DBConfiguration.java:302)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:213)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:328)
        at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:421)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:630)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:206)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:966)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:292)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
        at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:127)
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:126)
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:306)
        ... 23 more
```

Please help me out to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the dbproperties again.... and also verify whether you are able to connect to the oracle database from that particular machine..

Comment: Thanks Madhu...
I can execute sqoop eval command for the same query and I can see output on prompt..However, sqoop import command does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SQOOP Eval` function just acts on the RDBMS database and returns you the resultset. Here hadoop does not come into picture. 
`SQOOP Import` function tries to import the data from RDBMS and load it into HDFS.  For Sqoop Import to work as desired the db server should be reachable from all nodes in the cluster.

Comment: Thanks Madhu. Will get back to you on this.